# I can not find the octave.exe after installing octave, where is it?

Tags: python, octave

When installing oct2py library on Python, I was required to have GNU Octave installed in my path, in another word, setx PATH "%PATH%; where the folder  has the file “octave.exe”.

However, I can not find the octave.exe after installing octave using the installation packages released in https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/#install and I have tried all the three installation packages for Windows-64.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: never do `setx PATH "%PATH%"` as it sets the concatenated PATH (user+system) into the user variable. add the directory with windows env. variable editor instead

Comment: you have parallel installed the w64, w32 and w64-64 build? Not a very good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the lower version of GNU Octave and it will be OK!